Problems when exporting to QField
I'm on QGIS 3.34.9 using the QFieldSync Plugin 4.10.1. After the recent update I have been struggling to export projects to QField. I keep getting an error saying 'The project could not be converted into the export directory' I wonder if anyone could help?
